# Can I use roslyn and the new .net project format to create classes on build?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, roslyn, .net-core

I have a project using the new .net project format (`dnx` and `project.json`, currently using `dnvm` with mono-1.0.0-beta4, eventually want to use coreclr once they get `dnu restore` working on *NIX).

One of the common problems that I have with .net/C# is the desire to create code at compile time. For example, I have a virtual machine, which has a helper class like this:

```
public static class OpCodes {
    private readonly static IDictionary<byte, OpCode> _opcodes;

    public static OpCode MOV { get; private set; }
    public static OpCode ADD { get; private set; }
    public static OpCode SUB { get; private set; }

    static OpCodes() {
        // OpCode class contains info, e.g., the number of arguments
        MOV = new OpCode(0x00, "MOV", 2);
        ADD = new OpCode(0x01, "ADD", 0);
        SUB = new OpCode(0x02, "SUB", 0);

        _opcodes = new Dictionary<byte, OpCode> {
            { MOV.Code, MOV },
            { ADD.Code, ADD },
            { SUB.Code, SUB },
        };
    }

    public static OpCode Get(byte code) {
        OpCode result;
        if(_opcodes.TryGetValue(code, out result)) {
            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

As you see, there is a lot of plumbing in there:

1. A list of OpCodes
2. A Static Getter for each opcode
3. A way to look up an OpCode by it's binary value

The only thing I should have to create is #1, the actual meat of the application. Wrapping it in a dictionary and creating static getters should be done for me.

I know that "regular" Visual Studio has T4 templates, but these are a pain to run on build and seem to be tied to visual studio and thus no longer applicable.

Is there something I can do? I think I can create custom actions in the project.json (e.g., `dnx . regenopcodes`) but I don't know what I would be running here since I need to invoke Roslyn, find the list of OpCodes (maybe make an abstract `OpCodesBase` class), parse it, and generate the concrete `OpCodes` class for me.

Alternatively, I could create a opcodes.xml file and use normal text parsing to create a .cs from it, but I'm not sure how I'd configure that anytime I do `dnx . run` it first runs my generator and then does whatever it does normally.

Comment: but where those required OpCodes are specified ?

Comment: @Tigran Wherever it's easiest to get them into the build :) E.g., `internal abstract class OpCodeDefs { private readonly OpCode[] OpCodes = new [] { new OpCode(0x00, "MOV", 2) } }` or in an external file (`opcodes.xml`) or really, anything that works for the sake of the build. The application code will exclusively use the generated class and never needs to know about the source.

Comment: so `Dyamic` is not an option (constructing the real object by parsing the "source"), as you want type-safity. Right ? You *have to* have `static` methods (say), in other words.

Comment: @Tigran Hmmm... good point. Dynamic could work, but it would mean abandoning IntelliSense and a runtime penalty (premature optimization alert). It is an option, definitely.

Comment: If you are moving toward code generation, you loose an intellisense in any case. But in case of code generation you may benefit from compile time type checking, which is not something to underestimate, and kind of pity to ignore it, when we are still in the comfortable boundaries of static type language as `C#`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a precompilation step, similar to what Razor does to precompile views: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/64e726d2b26422c5452475627e4afaba307edec3/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/RazorPreCompileModule.cs

Here's another example: https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/e937e25ab3453ea86bda13c1297c41011dfda9de/ext/compiler/preprocess/Internalization.cs

And this is how you hook it up https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/3d20719b0a985b6960a3f87d9f5f9b6c3f71b7bc/src/Microsoft.Framework.Runtime/project.json#L16-L18

Comment: Thanks, that does it! Currently, the packages are still called .Interfaces in the main NuGet feed, but I assume they'll be renamed to .Abstractions soon-ish.

Comment: Is this answer still relevant?  Looks like `ICompileModule` has gone away.

Comment: Not anymore. `ICompileModule` is gone

Comment: how can i use generated c# classes via syntax generator to dump them in a dll via roslyn at runtime ?